# Preview of Xml file is unavailable in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-xml

I have been trying to solve the issue of xml preview but no results.

1.Changing the Theme 
but still I didn't get the result.

2.Infact done with changing dependencies then also facing same issue.

Image of my project

[image]

I am using Android Studio Latest version 4.2.1 for Windows 64-bit. Would anyone please help me out with it.

I tried and got to know how to resolve this problem
Here's the solution

Step 1 Delete that particular project if possible and save that file somewhere.

Step 2 After adding the palette components if you are facing autofill error then I have given steps for same below.

Add android:autofillHints="testhints"
Hope it will work for you.

Comment: Can you please click on the Red Exclamation Error symbol and share the errors?

Comment: Thanks for acknowledgement the error was regarding autofills.

Comment: So the issue is resolved?

Comment: Yes it got resolved